# Derivative with Constant

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> I need to calculate the derivative of the following function with respect to $x$:
>
> $$y = \ln(x) + 3x^2 + xc$$
>
> Where $c$ is an unknown constant.

The constant is what is throwing me for a loop.  I got $y' = \frac{1}{x} + 6x + 1$.  Is this correct?  Or is it just $y'=\frac{1}{x} + 6x$?  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The constant if it is a coefficient, stays. If added on or removed, ..then it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(cx)' = c$ ($c$ is just a number like $5$, and $(5x)' = 5$ too, not $1$), thus the answer should be:

$y' = 1/x + 6x + c$

Comment: That makes sense.   Thank you for the help

Comment: If an answer helped you, and solved your question, you can always give it an upvote and accept it as answer. Then, other users will know your question has been solved :)

Comment: @Math_QED He cannot give an upvote since he does not have 15 reputation yet. However, he can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer.

Comment: @projectilemotion Good to know! Thanks.

Comment: Returned the favor :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You have differentiated everything correctly, except for the $xc$ term.

Note the [constant factor rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_factor_rule_in_differentiation). If $c$ is a constant:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(cx)=c\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x)$$